# Optimize to get the most and least occurrences of pairs of from the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 10K list of 20 values like below in a dat file -

1. Medical, 24673, 23578, Orange, USA, Green, 25980, Canada, IT, 2M376, Engineering, 50925, 39421, Apple, India, Red, 77789, Mexico, FIN, 3R376
2. 24673, 23578, HongKong, Green, Management, 77789, Canada, HR, HL238, Engineering, 34009, 22173, Netflix, India, Jio, 77789, Mexico, OPS, 3R376, Orange

I ran below program to find the top 3 most occurred combination of 5 values like suppose [Medical, 24673, 23578, India, Mexico] - Occurred 1000 times. But program is keep running for very long time - more then 10 hours and then I stopped it. Can you please provide any optimize way to run the same.

```
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter
import ast

def most_frequent_combs(fn):
    counter1 = Counter()
    for ln in open(fn):
        unique_tokens = sorted(set(ast.literal_eval(ln)))
        combos = combinations(unique_tokens, 5)
        counter1 += Counter(combos)
    return counter1

fn = '/data/unix_framework/landing/summit/finalcollection.dat'
p = most_frequent_combs(fn)
print(p.most_common(3))
print(p.most_common()[-3])
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with `unique_tokens = sorted(set(ast.literal_eval(ln)))`, it seems `unique_tokens = ln.strip().split(',')` should be all you need?

Comment: thanks Nick.. I replaced unique_tokens as per your recommendation but still performance is not improved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, it is a bit long so bear with me. Lets assume that the vocabulary size of the data is $V$ meaning that there are $V$ distinct words to choose from. Now, represent the data as a matrix of $N$ rows (10K here) and $V$ columns, lets call it $A$. Now $A_{i,j} = 1$ if i-th data row contains the j-th word and 0 otherwise.

Now, pick the 5 columns from the matrix A which have highest $l_1$ norm and consider a vector $x$ of size $Vx1$ which has sparsity level of 5, meaning it is 1 at 5 locations and 0 everywhere else. In the first round $x$ will be 1 at locations which correspond to the top-5 $l_1$ norm columns. Compute $l_1$ norm of vector $A*x$. Store it in an array and then replace one of the previously 5 selected columns by the 6th highest $l_1$ norm column and compute norm of $A*x$ again. Keep track of the norms while replacing the selected columns one-by-one.  Do this until all the columns of A are exhausted.

This method should be faster (I am talking about orders of magnitude faster than looping over all possible combinations.

Comment: I realized that this solution is very similar to Greedy matching pursuit algorithm for sparse recovery problems.